# How to add gui text at run time in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a problem to display a text at run time in my game for a second , so I want to know if its possible to add or remove a GUI label to the seen at run time ?

Comment: Sure it is. Either make your call or don't.

Comment: Well, how do you display your text now? If it's a simple GUI.Label call, then just don't call that if you don't want it to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUI components get drawn on every frame. the OnGUI() function is just like the Update() function except that unlike the Update() function GUI components can be called in it.

You can think of OnGUI as a loop. It will call GUI components declared inside of it in order, then do it all over again every frame. So if you hook into this loop and block some components from being called at runtime, the very next frame those componants will not be rendered.

Here is a set of functions that can allow you to do this is a specified time:

```
private bool guiIsOn = true;

private void TurnOffGUIInSeconds(int seconds)
{
    StartCoroutine(_TurnOffGUIInSeconds(seconds));
}

private IEnumerator _TurnOffGUIInSeconds(int seconds)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
    guiIsOn = false;
}

void OnGUI()
{
    if(guiIsOn)
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(5,5,5,5), "Label text");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
void OnGUI() {
    if (textShouldBeShown) {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10f, 10f, 100f, 50f), "MyText");
    }
}
```